# This Product is not supported (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded [Visual Studio 2019 from the official site](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16). I am unable to install on my Windows 10 as it is showing the following error:

[image: Installer]

I am using Window 10 Pro whose screenshot is following:

[image: System Configuaration]

Comment: 4GB of RAM is going to be slow! Also, how much free disk space do you have on your system drive?

Comment: Also check the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements#visual-studio-2019-system-requirements) are fully met.

Comment: Also, maybe run Windows Update to make sure you have the latest/required service packs installed.

Comment: I have 216 GB of free space and also I have checked system requirements, but it is not working.

Comment: It requires Windows 10 version 1703 or higher. Are you OK there? It also requires a video card that supports a minimum display resolution of 720p. OK there?

Comment: How to check the version of Windows 10? I also have a Video card.

Comment: Settings -> System -> About to check Windows 10 version. Settings -> System -> Display to check display resolution.

Comment: It is showing Intel(R)  HD Graphics 300. Total available graphics memory 1664MB.

Comment: Copyright 2015 means you still use the old 15xx versions (TH1 or TH2), so update to 1909/2004.

Comment: Thank you all, it was related to window up-gradation.